# Re-parameterization to resolve non-identifiability in this squiggly model (linear combination of logistic functions)?

Tags: regression, bayesian, identifiability, sigmoid-curve

So my desire here is to be able to capture a variety of temporal dynamics governing the change in value of some feature of interest. I want the model to be able to represent, for example, bounded:

[image]

After a moment's thought, I decided to try summing two logistic functions together and found that they can replicate all these patterns, e.g.

[image]

(note: the black lines here would represent something like the expected value of a gamma distribution from which the rate of a Poisson-distributed count would be drawn, i.e. in gamma-poisson / negative-binomial regression)

The functional form for the model is given as the sum of two logistic functions, each represented as (here drawing on past experience in population ecology):

```
P <- function(K, r, t, L0){
  return(K / (1 + ((K-L0)/L0)*exp(-r*t) ))
}
```

and for inference (using Stan) I parameterize the starting $L_0$ as a beta-distributed proportion of the strictly-positive maximum K, with growth and decay processes having strictly negative rates r, respectively. The observations, meanwhile, are gamma-poisson distributed, which I parameterize with an expected rate given by the logistics and a separate scale parameter $\lambda$.

The model fits fine, both in Stan and using R's built-in non-linear optimization functions (`nlm()` etc.). With four observations there's plenty of uncertainty, but hey, that's life (and I'm trying to predict 4 observations with a 7 parameter model -- in contrast to the 4+ parameters that an "intercepts only" stair-step model w/ three phases might have):

[image]

(90% HPDI for expected rate in blue and posterior predictive interval in orange shaded)

With more observations, I hone in closer and closer to the true lambdas -- reassuring!

[image]

However, examining the joint posterior with pairwise scatterplots, I note a fair bit of non-identifiability in the model (here corresponding to the many-observation model fit above)

[image]

Some of it is completely innocuous, e.g. between log(K) and K. Some of it's probably fine, e.g. L0_prop and L0. But it looks like my rate and starting state are also non-identifiable! (not unexpected, necessarily -- the lower I start, the faster I need to go to catch up to the data in time!)

This property holds even when I give one of the logistics weight zero and just fit a single, 4 parameter model:

[image]

Both the starting state and the rate are putatively 'focal' parameters, but with non-identifiability their posterior variance is gonna be quite inflated (also, the experimental context here lacks a 'timepoint zero', so the starting state is uncertain and is in need of estimation). Otherwise I wouldn't be too worried (so long as the HMC sampler etc. is working ok). I already have pretty strong regularizing priors on these models, e.g. a beta(100,1) and beta(1,100) on my L0_prop, so I'm not entirely sure additional regularization to tease apart the two parameters is viable. But one ad hoc approach I might try could be to just simulate from lots of randomly generated models (sampled from the prior), fit them, and check if the patterns of non-identifiability I see are the same throughout all the fits. If it's the case that the rate is always a tenth the starting state or something I could maybe just hard-code that relation, or specify a highly informative prior on it, or something.

But that seems awfully hack-y, and I figured if this is a fairly common problem there might be some canonical solution to reparameterize these models. Any ideas, or other functions that could help represent the wiggly lines in my cartoon at the top? (something like a GP could, of course, describe these and many more relationships, but 1) my goals here are inference, rather than prediction, and 2) I don't actually want it to be *that* flexible)